# Copying data from one SQLite database to another

Tags: database, sqlite

I have 2 SQLite databases with common data but with different purposes and I wanted to avoid reinserting data, so I was wondering if it was possible to copy a whole table from one database to another?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You'll have to attach Database X with Database Y using the [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) command, then run the appropriate Insert Into commands for the tables you want to transfer.

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'db2.sqlite' as 'Y';
```

```
INSERT INTO X.TABLE SELECT * FROM Y.TABLE;
// "INSERT or IGNORE" if you want to ignore duplicates with same unique constraint
```

Or, if the columns are not matched up in order:

```
INSERT INTO X.TABLE(fieldname1, fieldname2) SELECT fieldname1, fieldname2 FROM Y.TABLE;
```

Comment: Also if SQLite Expert Personal program is using, it gives a chance to right click and ATTACH databases

Comment: You need to create the table first!

Comment: If you get a "(source) database locked" error when trying to detach it, you can use `COMMIT;` then detach it.

Comment: ... or `main` instead of `X`. the schema-name `main` refers to the main database, opened with `connect`. ([sqlite attach docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html))

Answer (score 88):

Easiest and correct way on a single line:

```
sqlite3 old.db ".dump mytable" | sqlite3 new.db
```

The primary key and the columns types will be kept.

Answer (score 58):

Consider a example where I have two databases namely allmsa.db and atlanta.db. Say the database allmsa.db has tables for all msas in US and database atlanta.db is empty.

Our target is to copy the table atlanta from allmsa.db to atlanta.db.

### Steps

1. sqlite3 atlanta.db(to go into atlanta database)
2. Attach allmsa.db. This can be done using the command `ATTACH '/mnt/fastaccessDS/core/csv/allmsa.db' AS AM;`
   note that we give the entire path of the database to be attached.
3. check the database list using `sqlite> .databases`
   you can see the output as

```
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /mnt/fastaccessDS/core/csv/atlanta.db                  
2    AM               /mnt/fastaccessDS/core/csv/allmsa.db
```

4. now you come to your actual target. Use the command 
   `INSERT INTO atlanta SELECT * FROM AM.atlanta;`

This should serve your purpose.

Comment: Using 'INSERT INTO atlanta SELECT * FROM AM.atlanta;' messed up things. It copied all the data but some fields were swapped! Don't use it. Instead use the command from the accepted answer, or even more explicitly: "INSERT INTO X.TABLE(Id, Value) SELECT Id, Value FROM Y.TABLE; This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 14):

For one time action, you can use .dump and .read.

Dump the table my_table from old_db.sqlite

```
c:\sqlite>sqlite3.exe old_db.sqlite
sqlite> .output mytable_dump.sql
sqlite> .dump my_table
sqlite> .quit
```

Read the dump into the new_db.sqlite assuming the table there does not exist

```
c:\sqlite>sqlite3.exe new_db.sqlite
sqlite> .read mytable_dump.sql
```

Now you have cloned your table. 
To do this for whole database, simply leave out the table name in the .dump command.

Bonus: The databases can have different encodings.

Comment: What if the table already exists, and want only to copy the values inside?

Comment: Then use the accepted answer from above.

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C code for copy Table from a Database to another Database

```
-(void) createCopyDatabase{

          NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
          NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

          NSString *maindbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"User.sqlite"];;

          NSString *newdbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"User_copy.sqlite"];
          NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
          char *error;

         if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newdbPath]) {
             [fileManager removeItemAtPath:newdbPath error:nil];
         }
         sqlite3 *database;
         //open database
        if (sqlite3_open([newdbPath UTF8String], &database)!=SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Error to open database");
        }

        NSString *attachQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE \"%@\" AS aDB",maindbPath];

       sqlite3_exec(database, [attachQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
       if (error) {
           NSLog(@"Error to Attach = %s",error);
       }

       //Query for copy Table
       NSString *sqlString = @"CREATE TABLE Info AS SELECT * FROM aDB.Info";
       sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlString UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error to copy database = %s",error);
        }

        //Query for copy Table with Where Clause

        sqlString = @"CREATE TABLE comments AS SELECT * FROM aDB.comments Where user_name = 'XYZ'";
        sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlString UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error to copy database = %s",error);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

**The Easiest way to do is through SQLite Studio**

If you don't have download from https://download.cnet.com/SQLiteStudio/3000-10254_4-75836135.html

Steps:

1.Add both the databases.

2.Click View tab and then databases as shown in the picture.

[image]

3.Right click the table you want to copy and copy it.[image]

4. Paste the table after right clicking the database where you want to paste.
   [image]

**Now you're done**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

First scenario: DB1.sqlite and DB2.sqlite have the same table(t1), but DB1 is more "up to date" than DB2.  If it's small, drop the table from DB2 and recreate it with the data:

```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db2.t1; CREATE TABLE db2.t1 AS SELECT * FROM db1.t1;
```

Second scenario: If it's a large table, you may be better off with an `INSERT if not exists` type solution.  If you have a `Unique Key` column it's more straight forward, otherwise you'd need to use a combination of fields (maybe every field) and at some point it's still faster to just `drop` and re-`create` the table; it's always more straight forward (less thinking required).

---

THE SETUP: open SQLite without a DB which creates a `temporary` in memory `main` database, then `attach` DB1.sqlite and DB2.sqlite

```
> sqlite3
sqlite> ATTACH "DB1.sqlite" AS db1
sqlite> ATTACH "DB2.sqlite" AS db2
```

and use `.databases` to see the attached databases and their files.

```
sqlite> .databases
main: 
db1: /db/DB1.sqlite
db2: /db/DB2.sqlite
```

Comment: NOTE: This does not preserve `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY` attributes, so if you have those, you'll either need to `DROP TABLE` and manually `CREATE` and `INSERT` or use the `.dump` and `.read`  [method mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33298298/1118820) by @Thinkeye.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), you can copy the table from one db to another in following steps:

0. Open two instances of the app and load the source db and target db side by side.
1. If the target db does not have the table, "Copy Create Statement" from the source db and then paste the sql statement in "Execute SQL" tab and run the sql to create the table.
2. In the source db, export the table as a CSV file.
3. In the target db, import the CSV file to the table with the same table name. The app will ask you do you want to import the data to the existing table, click yes. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move data from a sql server compact database to sqlite, so using sql server 2008 you can right click on the table and select 'Script Table To' and then 'Data to Inserts'. Copy the insert statements remove the 'GO' statements and it executed successfully when applied to the sqlite database using the 'DB Browser for Sqlite' app.