# SQLite on iOS - SQL to copy from one file to another

Tags: c#, sql, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I have 2 database files in my iOS app:

- An original database (readonly, kept in my app's home directory)
- The user's database (kept in the user's `Documents` folder)

I need to run a SQL query to copy from the original database to the user's,  something like:

```
INSERT INTO UserDatabase.MyTable
SELECT * FROM OriginalDatabase.MyTable;
```

Is this possible from SQLite running on iOS?  The problem is the two databases are in different folder.  I would like to avoid doing this work in code (C#) which is the obvious way to do it, just much slower.

My app is written with C#/MonoTouch, but that is probably irrelevant.

Comment: Do you want to copy the entire Database, a table or particular records based on an query ?

Comment: Particular records exactly like my example above, there might be a `WHERE` clause, joins etc., but I put a simple example.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-db-to-another

Comment: Thanks, Peter I will try it.  I am wondering if this will work in my situation, however.  One database is in a readonly folder (I just need to `SELECT` from it), we will see if it works.

Comment: This works on the desktop (we are about to try on the device shortly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved with @Peter M's link.

Here is the SQL to do this on iOS:

```
    ATTACH DATABASE '../YourApp.app/YourDatabase.db' AS OriginalDatabase;

    INSERT INTO Main.MyTable
    SELECT * FROM OriginalDatabase.MyTable;

    DETACH DATABASE OriginalDatabase;
```

Note the use of `Main`, this is the database you are connected to with `SqliteConnection`, in my case it was located in the `Documents` folder.

You can do anything you need against the `OriginalDatabase`, joins, subselects, etc.