# Insert all tables from one database to another database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, fmdb

I've seen code to insert data from one table to another once you attach the database like in this post:

[SQLite on iOS - SQL to copy from one file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350894/sqlite-on-ios-sql-to-copy-from-one-file-to-another)

However, I don't want to be table specific.  I just want to grab all the data from one database (the one in our bundle), and copy it to our new database in the documents directory.  Can this be done?  If so, what are the commands for it?

I tried

```
INSERT INTO newDBPath SELECT * FROM 'BundleDatabase'
```

BundleDatabase is the database that I attached.  I am using FMDatabase and when I do:

```
BOOL success = [newDBPath executeUpdate:theAboveQuery];
```

I do get a success as YES.  But I get nothing in the new table.  So I'm wondering if it's even possible to insert all the tables from one database to another without being table specific?

Comment: Seems to me this discussion may be helpful to your query here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471003/copying-table-in-one-db-to-another-db-in-ios-by-sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like indices are database specific and cannot be brought over from the research I've done.