# How do I import tables from another database in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have SQLite databases named `database1` with a table `t1` and `database2` with a table `t2`. I want to import table `t2` from `database2` into `database1`. What command(s) should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying data from one sqlite db to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-db-to-another)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Open `database2` with the [`sqlite3` command-line tool](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) and read the table definition with the command `.schema t2`.
(Alternatively, use any other tool that allows to read the table definition.)

Then open `database1`, [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the other database with the command:

```
ATTACH 'database2file' AS db2;
```

then create the table `t2`, and copy the data over with:

```
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM db2.t2;
```

Answer (score 16):

Shell command:

```
sqlite3 database1
```

In SQLite shell:

```
sqlite> ATTACH 'database2' AS db2;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT * FROM db2.t2;
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the sqlite3 `.dump` command to pipe the dump output into the other db. It takes an optional argument with the table name.

```
db1=~/mydb1.sqlite 
db2=~/mydb2.sqlite
t=t2

sqlite3 "$db2" ".dump $t" | sqlite3 "$db1"
```

If you have no common tables in both databases, you can leave out the table name and copy all tables.

If the tables are big, this may be slow because it will do INSERTs. If they are huge, and it is really too slow, maybe `.import` would be faster. You could try something like

```
sqlite3 "$db2" ".schema $t" | sqlite3 "$db1"
sqlite3 "$db2" "SELECT * FROM $t" | sqlite3 "$db1" ".import /dev/stdin $t"
```