# SQLITE: How to create table as another table and set default value?

Tags: sqlite

the code i use:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE `new_form` as select * from `form`
```

but new_form can't have default value

like column ID can't auto_increment.

Comment: You can find original table creation script in `sqlite_master` table, modify it (replace table name) and execute new script.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with CREATE TABLE … AS SELECT ….

You have to [create the new table manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13206501/11654) before copying the data.