# to export sqlite db using java

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to export/save as the sqlite db to another space (ex: C、D、anywhere )
by using java ...
I hope someone can help me to solve this question..
the view is 
maybe use java swing make a interface and this program has a sqlite db and we have a button(save as) to press and can do save as this db to another space 
I cant find many resource to look up , so I hope someone can help me to complete this program .
I will be very happy and thank you.

Comment: Here is not Freelancer. It's called Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite allows you to `ATTACH` another database file (which can be located anywhere). Then, you just use SQL statements to [copy the contents over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2359205/301832). Here's the sort of thing you want.

```sql
ATTACH DATABASE '/the/path/to/the/other/db.sqlite' AS otherdb;
CREATE TABLE otherdb.theTableName (...);
INSERT INTO otherdb.theTableName SELECT * FROM main.theTableName;
```

Alternatively, *with no connections open* just copy the DB file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try{
        filename = null;
        HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);           
        rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Invoice No");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Date");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Customer");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Reference No.");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Qty");


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/animal1", "root", "315921");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from few1");
            int i=1;
            while(rs.next()){
            HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)i);
            row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("Invoice"));
            row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("Date"));
            row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("Customer"));
            row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getString("Reference"));
            row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString("Qty"));

            i++;
            }



             JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
             int retval = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
             if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                filename  = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                if (!filename.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")) {
                    filename = new File(filename.getParentFile(), filename.getName() + ".xls");

                }  
             }


            FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
            hwb.write(fileOut);  
            fileOut.close();


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your excel file has been generated!");


            } catch ( IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex ) {
                System.out.println(ex);

            }
```

Its for Java export MySQL data in Microsoft excel.

Comment: Could you please try to reformat the code such that it is properly aligned and formatted.