# importing data from existing Ruby On Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, import, installation

I have just started learning Ruby On Rails. I am setting up an existing Rails project to my local machine. i hope all the process till yet are ok but i dont get how to import the table data from the existing project also i dont know where the data is stored in Rails? 
i have a **db/development.sqlite3** file i have ran ***'rake db:schema:load'*** and **'rake db:migrate'** but i guess these commands have just set up the database structure, but not the data insert. It will be a great if anyone can help me this in easiest way along with telling me few fundamentals

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-db-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question can be answered in two ways, depending on what data you have already:

---

[**rake db:seed**](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html)

Like `rake db:migrate`, `db:seed` basically takes what's in your `db/seeds.rb` & applies to your database. The contents of `seeds.db` is just simple ActiveRecord:

```
Model.create({attr: value, attr: value})
```

If you have "raw" data you'll like to include, you should open your `seeds.rb` file, populate with ActiveRecord commands (like above), and then run `rake db:seed` to get it onto the server

---

**DB Porting**

If you have data in another stack, you'll have to "port" (I think?) the data. There is no "Rails way" to do this, as everyone's stack / db is different

The process will basically be to create the right tables in both databases with `rake db:migrate`, download the relevant data from your old stack, and then upload to your new one