# SQLite: Easiest way to copy a table from one database to another?

Tags: sqlite

I have two sqlite databases and want to copy a table from database A to database B. The other tables in database A should not be copied. What is the easiest way to do that in Java?

I could definitively do something like Select * from A and then insert all of this into database B, but shouldn't there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying data from one sqlite db to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-db-to-another)

Answer (score 40):

Open the database you are copying from, then run this code to attach the database you are copying to and then copy a table over.

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;

INSERT INTO other.tbl
SELECT * FROM main.tbl;
```

Comment: Lastly, run `DETACH other;`.

Comment: @Colonel How to do ATTACH command in Web Sql using Javascript?

Comment: othe.tbl is table that I should create before doing this query? main is a name of db copying from?

Answer (score 10):

Why do you want to do that in Java? You can do it directly at the command-line, by dumping your table, and reading it into your other database :

```
sqlite3 A.sqlite ".dump some_table" | sqlite3 B.sqlite
```

If you need to drop the existing table in "B.sqlite" first, you can use the `-cmd` switch in the second part, to "run command before reading stdin" :

```
sqlite3 A.sqlite ".dump some_table" \
| sqlite3 -cmd "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table" B.sqlite
```

Comment: Most elegant method!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do get a "table XYZ already exists" error. Is there some flag to overwrite?