# Migrating SQLite3 database (w/ very similar schema) to already created Django models

Tags: django, sqlite, migration

Please go easy on me, I literally just started using Django at 3am this morning...

As part of a school project, I wrote a Python script to scrape data, generate SQLite3 tables and insert records from a Python dictionary into said tables. The schema of this SQLite3 db looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE state (
                        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                        name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
                      );
CREATE TABLE city (
                        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                        name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
                      );
CREATE TABLE restaurant (
                        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                        name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                        rating FLOAT,
                        url VARCHAR(300),
                        price VARCHAR(4),
                        review_count INT,
                        street VARCHAR(100),
                        city VARCHAR(100),
                        state VARCHAR(2),
                        country VARCHAR(100),
                        zip_code INT,
                        phone VARCHAR(20),
                        image_url VARCHAR(300)
                      );
CREATE TABLE category (
                        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                        title VARCHAR(100)
                      );
CREATE TABLE restaurant_by_category (
                        restaurant_id INT,
                        category_id INT,
                        FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurant,
                        FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category
                      );
CREATE TABLE review (
                        url VARCHAR(300) PRIMARY KEY,
                        restaurant_id INT,
                        rating FLOAT,
                        name VARCHAR(100),
                        time VARCHAR(100),
                        text VARCHAR(300)
                      );
```

Weeks after making this database, I then decided to start making the web app using Django. I have a (basically) fully operational Django app with a SQLite3 backend whose `models.py` looks like this:

```
class City(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class State(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Restaurant(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True,
      blank=True)
  url = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
  price = models.CharField(max_length=4)
  review_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, null=True)
  image_url = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
  city = models.ForeignKey(City, blank=True, null=True)
  state = models.ForeignKey(State, blank=True, null=True)
  state_abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
  zip_code = USZipCodeField(blank=True, null=True)
  street = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Review(models.Model):
  url = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  restaurant_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True,
      blank=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
  time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class Category(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class RestaurantByCategory(models.Model):
  restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
  category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

My preexisting SQLite3 database and my Django models are almost exactly the same except for these two differences:

- The `Restaurant` model has an additional field `state_abbreviation` which is actually `state` in the SQLite3 database -- `state` in the `Restaurant` model does not have a corollary field in the SQlite3 database. When I migrate the SQLite3 database over to Django, I don't care if the `state` field in the Django model is `None` because there are only three states in the database and I can easily add that in manually via the admin page, but I *do* want the `state` attributes in the SQLite3 database to be entered into the `state_abbreviation` fields of my `Restaurant` model instances.
- There are several field type mismatches such as the `DateTimeField` in `Review`, the `USZipCodeField` in `Restaurant`, or the `ForeignKey` in `Restaurant`...all of these are declared as `VARCHAR` in my SQLite3 database

My question is, how can I automatically migrate my existing SQLite3 database into my new Django models quickly and safely?

Here is what I've researched:

- [Using `makemigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to make a migrations file and then [writing a `RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) function to do a batch insert into my models.
- [Using fixtures, dumpdata, and loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/) to store my preexisting schema and then load it into the Django models.

Here is why I'm stuck and can't figure out what to do next:

- The later option (fixtures) doesn't seem like what I'm looking for because, from what I understand, this would only work if I was migrating to a different database from another database where both the new and the old databases are in my Django app...my situation requires dumping data from an SQLite schema which I don't think is possible -- at least not in a way that solves my problem.
- The former option seems kinda like what I want, except the example makes it seem as though I'd have to manually write model instances for all the records anyway which wouldn't be any better than just entering all the records in through the admin page.
- I also feel like the field type mismatches and slightly differing schema (see the differences of state/state_abbreviation attributes in `Restaurant`) would throw off this migration process even if there was a way to automatically migrate from my SQLite3 database to my Django models.

So, am I pretty much stuck with entering in records manually or is there an easy way to perform this migration? There are only about 400 records in the SQLite3 table, so I *could* manually enter a bunch in to get a working demo before presenting this project tomorrow, but I also have a lot of other things to do before this is finished and I'd rather not spend 3 hours manually entering records.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Additional options: Rewrite the models in Django and [copy the data from the old database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220677/sqlite-easiest-way-to-copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another/29221750#29221750); or use the database as-is and [disable Django's model management for the models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed)

Comment: Thanks @ColonelThirtyTwo -- the first link + plus a migration file did the trick for me.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I think that should really be an answer (with a little more detail of course)

Comment: if he doesn't answer, please add your own answer explaining what you did. Because this is a good question