# Copying a table wholesale in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

*I'm aware of that a very similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220677/sqlite-easiest-way-to-copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another/29221750). However, I'm unable to implement the solution there given: when I try to run the script beginning `ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;` I get an error saying that it couldn't connect to other.db, despite there being such a file in that directory.*

---

I've got **two SQLite databases**, database_a.db and database_b.db. I want to copy a table, named Table_to_be_copied, from database_a.db to database_b.db. Table_to_be_copied has **no analogue** or equivalent in database_b.db and **I can't assume anything** about said table except for its name; I can't assume how many columns it has, or what they're called.

I want to copy Table_to_be_copied **wholesale**: name, columns and rows. What's the easiest way of achieving this? (For what it's worth, I'm connecting to the databases via **Python** scripts.) I know one way of copying the table, but it's not very elegant: it involves writing a script which reads all the data required from database_a.db into memory and then recreating the table from scratch in database_b.db. But is there a better way?

Comment: `ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;` how about removing the quotations, and using this instead? `ATTACH DATABASE other.db AS other;`

Comment: @ChloroxBleach69 Here's what that gives me: `Result: no such column: combined_data.db` // `At line 1:` // `ATTACH DATABASE combined_data.db AS combined;`

Comment: @ChloroxBleach69 I'm running the script via the DB Browser for SQLite, if that makes a difference. (I tend to test the waters by running scripts through said browser. For more proper stuff I use Python.)

Comment: Hmm how about trying c.execute("ATTACH DATABASE ? AS combined", ("other.db",))`

Comment: @ChloroxBleach69 Thanks for the tip. After a bit more weeping and gnashing of teeth, I've managed to get it working.

Comment: if you did, can you submit the answer here?

Comment: @ChloroxBleach69 I did!

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the shortest snippet of **Python** code for **copying an SQLite table wholesale** is as follows.

Say that you want to copy a table called *Platform_Specifics* from *database_a.db* to *database_b.db*. Then run:

```py
import sqlite3

def create_local_specifics():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("database_b.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query0 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Platform_Specifics;"
    query1 = ("CREATE TABLE Platform_Specifics\n"+
              "(\n"+
              "    specific TEXT,\n"+
              "    value TEXT,\n"+
              "    PRIMARY KEY(specific)\n"+
              ");")
    cursor.execute(query0)
    cursor.execute(query1)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

def transfer_local_specifics():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("database_a.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query0 = "ATTACH DATABASE 'database_b.db' AS other;"
    query1 = ("INSERT INTO other.Platform_Specifics "+
              "SELECT * FROM Platform_Specifics;")
    query2 = "DETACH other;"
    cursor.execute(query0)
    cursor.execute(query1)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.execute(query2)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

def copy_local_specifics():
    create_local_specifics()
    transfer_local_specifics()

copy_local_specifics()
```

One obvious drawback of the above: you do need to know the `CREATE` script for the table you wish to copy, which may be cumbersome.

Of course, I'd be eager to hear from anyone who knows of a shorter and/or simpler method.