# Attaching one database to another database by command line doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to follow second answer from [Copying data from one SQLite database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-database-to-another)

I've got two classes: 
DatabasePayments.java and DatabaseClients.java

DatabasePayments.java:

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "paymentsDatabase";
// Table name
private static final String TABLE_PAYMENTS = "payments";
```

DatabaseClients.java:

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "clientsDatabase";

//TABLE NAMES
private static final String TABLE_CLIENTS = "clients";
```

And I want to use data from clientsDatabase in paymentsDatabase so I call commands exactly like in second answer from linked question from beggining of my question or [SQLITE ATTACH documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) but I don't know if my command are calling.

```
C:\Users\Rafaello\AndroidStudioProjects\Debtors>sqlite3
sqlite> .open DatabaseClients.java
sqlite> .open clientsDatabase
sqlite> .open clients
sqlite>
```

or

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO paymentsDatabase.payments SELECT  * FROM clientsDatabase.clients
   ...>
```

and every time I write some command, empty `sqlite>` or `...>` appear and I don't know if anything work or not

Comment: Semi-colons are important in SQLite... And why are you opening a Java file?

Comment: Why not just use this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/40353567/2308683

Comment: C:\Users\Rafaello\AndroidStudioProjects\Debtors>sqlite3 clientsDatabe.db ".dump clients" | sqlite paymentsDatabase.db; doesn't work too

Comment: Semi colons are not important to CMD

Comment: 1) Your spelled `clientsDatabase` wrong 2) "doesn't work" means nothing to me. According to that answer it should dump the clients table into the other database.

Comment: @cricket_007 Do You know what is the correct command to make it work properly?

Comment: I do not. That post you linked to "should work" fine. The `sqlite3` command can only open one database file at a time, I think, though, and it cannot open `java` files, then your commands must end with semi-colons to not get `...>`