# How to export a sqlite database that I updated

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code that imports an existing database and updates it.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Test.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT test FROM Test')
data = c.fetchall()
c.execute('UPDATE BLAH BLAH BLAH')
c.commit()
```

But I want to export that data in different name, so I don't overwrite the database that I'm opening.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying data from one SQLite database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-database-to-another)

Comment: google search, first hit for: `sqllite copy database`

Comment: you can take a copy of the DB first, then do your updates on the copy...

Comment: google search, first hit for `sqllite export database`: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/

Comment: [how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Test.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('ATTACH DATABASE "Test2.sqlite" as Test2')
c.execute('INSERT INTO Test2.Table1 SELECT Column1 FROM Table1')
c.execute('SELECT Column1 FROM Test2.Table1')
data = c.fetchall()
c.execute('UPDATE Test2.Table1 SET Column1 = 1 WHERE Column1 = 0')
c.close()
```