# how to copy all tables in sqlite's database from one database to another using c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

please help me for:
how to copy all tables in sqlite's database from one database to another using c++

I have a database file,I want to copy all table to another database and using c++ language,I don't know how to Loop read all table in the original database an how to copy them to another database using c++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying data from one SQLite database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-database-to-another)

Comment: Read up on the backup api.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a copy of the database file with the new database name, that is assuming you want all the data as well. This  can be done without connecting to/opening the database by standard File handling.

- The database name is only significant as the file name.

Another way is to use `VACUUM INTO 'file';` again this copies all data, this does require the database to have been connected as the above is an SQL statement.

- e.g. `VACUUM INTO 'E:\Navicat\SQlite Databases\myOtherDBName';` (Windows)
- see [VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)

If you don't want the data then when connected to the new database you can delete the rows in all the tables followed by a VACUUM (if you wish). This would probably be best done within a transaction.

Comment: But I need using c++ to finish it

Comment: @JiangKai either can be done in c++ (or many languages).